# Dynamic form with jquery and calculations server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a rails app that generates quotes to rent out meeting rooms using forms. Each quote requires a number of inputs pulled from different models in the database (room, rate) and some other inputs specific to each quote (hours, extras) that are filled directly into the quote form.

With all that data I run some calculations in the model to get the prices of a particular meeting room for a specific day.

I'm trying to show the results of those calculations dynamically on the same page, next to the form.

For that, I have:

-> A form, with nested fields.

```
<%= form_for(@quote) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :hours, class: "form-control" calculation %>
  <%= f.text_field :extras, class: "form-control calculation" %>
  .
  .
  <%= f.fields_for :contact, @quote.contact do |contact_form| %>
    <%= contact_form.text_field :email, class: "form-control"%>
  <% end %>
  .
  .
  <%= f.fields_for :room, @quote.room do |room_form| %>
    <%= room_form.collection_select :room_id, Room.all, :id, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>  
  .
  .
  .             
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

-> Some logic in the Quote model

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :room
  has_one :booking
  belongs_to :rate
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :booking

  validates :rate_id, presence: true
  validates :contact_id, presence: true
  validates :room_id, presence: true

def calculate_quote
    (half_day_price + 
     full_day_price + 
     extended_day_price + 
     hours_price) / 
     calculate_discount 
end

def calculate_discount
    if self.rate
        self.rate.discount_rate / 100
    else
        return 1
    end
.
.
.
end
```

-> A method in the controller that should create a json response with the result of those calculations.

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :pricing]

def pricing
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @quote, methods: [:calculate_quote, :half_day_price], only: [:id, :calculate_quote, :half_day_price, :full_day_price] }
    end
end 
.
.
.
```

-> And everything into params

```
def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:half_days, :full_days, :extended_days, :extras, :rate, :discount, :rate_id, contact_attributes: [:id, :name, :email, :phone], booking_attributes: [:id, :start_date, :end_date, :start_time, :finish_time])
end
```

-> And a js file that should pick up data from that json:

```
$(function(){
  $(".calculation").change(function(){
    var rate = $("#quote_rate_id").val();
    var room = $("#quote_room_room_id").val();
    var half_days = $("#quote_half_days").val();
    var full_days = $("#quote_full_days");
    var extended_days = $("#quote_extended_days");
    var extras = $("#quote_extras");
    var discount = $("#quote_discount");
    jQuery.getJSON(url? + "/pricing", { rate: rate, room: room,  half_days: half_days, full_days: full_days, extended_days: extended_days, hours: hours, extras: extras, discount: discounti}, function(data){
    $("#half-days-price").text(data.half_days);
    $("full-days-price").text(data.full_days);

    });
});
});
```

Following this approach I'm stuck trying to find the right routes and urls to have this form working under quotes/new while passing the id of the quote object in json before it's saved. And that makes me wonder, is this the right approach to begin with? Should I be following a different path?

I would appreciate some fresh ideas.

Comment: Are all these values needed for calculating the price? Because it appears you're binding the server call to your `input.calculation` form element. Meaning everytime you calculation input field changes, the method runs.

Comment: Yes, many fields are involved in the calculations, those denoted by that tag. The form works the way is intended to, the bits I'm confused about is making the jquery part work with the controller.